# how can I copy arrays with their keys and values with a foreach loop in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, session, loops

in php, I cna use foreach $key->$value but in c sharp i couldn't find a similar solution, I have data values and I want to save them to session with their keys will be column names.so I'm tring to copy a datarow to session which will get key names from column names of datarow with a loop.

Comment: Arrays don't have keys... They have an integer index... Can you clarify?

Comment: in PHP arrays and dictionaries are the same thing (i.e. the key is the index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a dictionary, you can use:

```
foreach (var item in dict) {
  var key = item.Key;
  var value = item.Value;
}
```

Comment: It's not a `Dictionary`. It's a `DataRow`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to iterate the `DataTable`:

```
foreach(DataColumn c in row.Table.Columns) {
    string key = c.ColumnName;
    string value = row[key];

    // Copy into session here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a C# data type that supports keys and values and is enumerable in a ForEach loop, look into the Dictionary class.

Answer (score 0):

Convert this PHP code into ASP :

```
$handle = fopen("log.txt", "a");

foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {

fwrite($handle, $variable);

fwrite($handle, "=");

fwrite($handle, $value);

fwrite($handle, "\r\n");

}
```